# MVC4 - how to use EditorFor() with dynamic form data from a database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tables in my database called Sections and Fields.  Sections contain Fields.  Fields can be a textbox or checkbox.  I am using this to dynamically create HTML forms for data entry.

I have a view which is bound to a Section:

```
@model Data.Section    

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveSection", "MyController"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="fields">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fields)    
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
}
```

I then have an editor template for Field in my EditorTemplates folder:

```
@model Photon.Data.Field

@if (Model != null)
{
    <span class="label">@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)</span>

    <span class="field">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FieldValues)
    </span>
}
```

(I have an editor template for FieldValues but that's not relevant here I don't think.)

The above solution works GREAT for listing textboxes and checkboxes.  When a user edits them and then clicks Save, it posts back to my controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveSection(Section model)
    {
        // do some magic
    }
```

My Section model that is passed into my method is valid, and bound to the fields from the page.

**Here's where I am stumped**:
In some of these sections, the fields will need to be laid out in a specific html format (like horizontally or to look like a form from a document) -- basically they can't just be listed.  So my thought was to assign a section a template name, then load that template with all the fields, like:

```
<div class="fields">
@if (Model.IsTemplated)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fields, Model.TemplateName)    
}
else
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fields)    
}
</div>
```

What would my view for Model.TemplateName look like if I wanted to lay all of these fields out in a specific html format that is not just a list?

Here's where I'm at:

```
@model IEnumerable<Data.Field>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            How do I display one field here with EditorFor?
        </td>
        <td>
            How do I display another field here with EditorFor?
        </td>
        <td>
            How do I display and another field here with EditorFor?
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Ideas?  Am I going along the right path here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you manage to arrive at the final View, then laying the fields out in the table row should be similar to this?

```
...
<tr>
    @foreach(var fld in Model)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.EditorFor(m => fld)
        </td>
    }
</tr>
...
```

(I don't sit in front of Visual Studio with a razor designer right now, so I apologize for any typos..)

Comment: Yeah see, that's the issue right there...when this is called from the view: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fields, Model.TemplateName) it calls the EditorTemplate 3 times (3 fields).  So the solution your provided does display them all in a row, however, it shows each field 3 times, so I end up with 9 form fields instead of 3.
<br/>
Also, what if I wanted a very specific layout, say the fields all represented an address, so two fields on the top row, 3 on the bottom.  And what if these templates got very complex?

Comment: What? You actually get three tables beneath each other, each having a single row with three columns? That sounds weird.. I'm quite new to this MVC stuff myself, but I've successfully used [partial views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962(v=vs.108).aspx) in a similar situation. You could try replacing **@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Fields, Model.TemplateName)** with **@Html.RenderPartial(Model.TemplateName, Model.Fields)**

Comment: I dont think you're supposed to use a partial view within a beginform() block